# What is the correct syntax for using an expression in a Linq query?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I created an expression for the purposes of filtering a Linq statement:

```
Expression<Func<Driver, bool>> expression = null;
```

That is defined based on the value of an action's parameter:

```
switch (driver_type)
{
    case "all": // remove any filters related to `driver_type`
        expression = d => true;
        break;
    case "licensed":
        expression = d => !(new string[] { "A", "B" }).Contains(d.DriverType);
        break;
    case "unlicensed":
        expression = d => d.DriverType == "D";
        break;
    default:
        expression = d => !(new string[] { "A", "B" }).Contains(d.DriverType);
        break;
}
```

Which is then used to filter a Linq query:

```
drivers = await (
    from driver in _context.Drivers
    where
        (driver.Active == true)
        && expression <-- invalid
    orderby driver.LastName, driver.FirstName
    select driver
).ToListAsync();
```

What's the correct syntax for this?

Incidentally, is there a way for the `default` switch option to use the expression that is generated by the `licensed` option?

Comment: You can chain it on by adding an additional call to `.Where(expression)` before the `ToListAsync()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to pass it as a lambda. To make it more readable you could change the whole expression to use lambdas.

```
drivers = await _context.Drivers
    .Where(driver => driver.Active)
    .Where(expression)
    .OrderBy(driver => driver.LastName)
    .ThenBy(driver => driver.FirstName)
    .ToListAsync();
```